# Adding a space between string words

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function named `string_processing` that takes a list of
> strings as input and returns an all-lowercase string with no
> punctuation. There should be a space between each word. You do not
> have to check for edge cases.

Here is my code:

```
import string

def string_processing(string_list):
    str1 = ""
    for word in string_list:
        str1 += ''.join(x for x in word if x not in string.punctuation)
    return str1

string_processing(['hello,', 'world!'])
string_processing(['test...', 'me....', 'please'])
```

My output:

```
'helloworld'
'testmeplease'
```

Expected output:

```
'hello world'
'test me please'
```

How to add a space in just between words?

Comment: Do not post you assignments verbating expecting people to do your homework. Instead, state what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Just put space in your code in that line `str1 += ' ' + ''.join(x for x in word if x not in string.punctuation)`

Comment: @YasserKhalil This will add an unwanted space at the start of the string

Answer (score 2):

You just need to keep all the words separate and then join them later with a space between them:

```py
import string
def string_processing(string_list):
    ret = []
    for word in string_list:
        ret.append(''.join(x for x in word if x not in string.punctuation))
    return ' '.join(ret)

print(string_processing(['hello,', 'world!']))
print(string_processing(['test...', 'me....', 'please']))
```

Output:

```
hello world
test me please
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import string
def string_processing(string_list):
    str1 = ""
    for word in string_list:
        st = ''.join(x for x in word if x not in string.punctuation)
        str1 += f"{st} "  #<-------- here
    
    return str1.rstrip() #<------- here

string_processing(['hello,', 'world!'])
string_processing(['test...', 'me....', 'please'])
```

---

**using regex:**

```
import re
li = ['hello...,', 'world!']
st = " ".join(re.compile('\w+').findall("".join(li)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`re`gex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), remove every non-letter and then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a space:

```py
import re

def string_processing(string_list):
    return ' '.join(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', word) for word in string_list)

print(string_processing(['hello,', 'world!']))
print(string_processing(['test...', 'me....', 'please']))
```

Gives:

```
hello world
test me please
```

Comment: I didn't think of removing non letter :-? Nice one +1

Answer (score 0):

We can use the re library to process the words and add a space between them

```
import re
string = 'HelloWorld'
print(re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', string))
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question

Answer (score 0):

The following code could help.

```
import string
def string_processing(string_list):

    for i,word in enumerate(string_list):
        string_list[i] = word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()

    str1 = " ".join(string_list)

    return str1

string_processing(['hello,', 'world!'])
string_processing(['test...', 'me....', 'please'])
```